# MYSQL ROUND & SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I have a query...

```
ROUND(100 - (OnSale) / (WholeSalePrice) * 100) AS DiscountIS
```

OnSale = 15, WholeSalePrice = 20
Result: DiscountIS = 25

That gives me the % that the `OnSale` price is off of the `WholeSalePrice`.

But if the `OnSale` price is 0 it displays 100 as the value of `DiscountIS`. What would the correct query be if I wanted it to return 0 as the `DiscountIS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select CASE 
             When OnSale = 0 Then 0 
       ELSE 
             ROUND(100 - (OnSale) / (WholeSalePrice) * 100)
       END
       AS DiscountIS
```